# Can't Connect to VPN in LTS 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, vpn, openvpn, cisco

I am still using 16.04. I plan on upgrading to 20.04 when the academic year is over.

I recently did something stupid and tried to install OpenPLC Editor, which involved uninstalling a bunch of things, including some Python and GTK stuff. Now, I can't connect to VPN. At first I couldn't connect to both my school's VPN and NordVPN, but I deleted and reinstalled the NordVPN connection, and it now works. My school's VPN connection does not work. Here are the instructions for getting on the school's VPN https://faculty-web.msoe.edu/hasker/resources/vpn.html

EDIT: Here is some more information:

1) I just upgraded to 18.04

2) Changing the password information to "Store the password for all users" got it to at least try.

3)

```
user@machine:~$ systemctl status network-manager

<snip>

May 26 01:24:17 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <info>  [1590474257.5085] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
May 26 01:24:17 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <info>  [1590474257.5336] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
May 26 01:24:17 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <info>  [1590474257.5337] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 26 01:24:48 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: /usr/sbin/vpnc: no response from target
May 26 01:24:48 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <info>  [1590474288.0457] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
May 26 01:24:48 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <warn>  [1590474288.0651] vpn-connection[0x560a256a4600,94b63c87-198c-4e2e-90d1-e0f4320f5e10,"MSOE SSL VPN",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed 
May 26 01:24:48 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <warn>  [1590474288.0652] vpn-connection[0x560a256a4600,94b63c87-198c-4e2e-90d1-e0f4320f5e10,"MSOE SSL VPN",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed 
May 26 01:24:48 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <info>  [1590474288.0652] vpn-connection[0x560a256a4600,94b63c87-198c-4e2e-90d1-e0f4320f5e10,"MSOE SSL VPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping
May 26 01:24:48 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <info>  [1590474288.0652] vpn-connection[0x560a256a4600,94b63c87-198c-4e2e-90d1-e0f4320f5e10,"MSOE SSL VPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped 
May 26 01:24:48 machine.domain.com NetworkManager[3270]: <info>  [1590474288.0697] vpn-connection[0x560a256a4600,94b63c87-198c-4e2e-90d1-e0f4320f5e10,"MSOE SSL VPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

There appears to be some issue with ifupdown.

UPDATE: I just set up my server and took off the firewall exceptions for the desktop and tried to load NordVPN through OpenVPN, and it wan't load either now. I supposedly have NordVPN running on my desktop through the Nord Linux app, but I don't know how to verify that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you connecting to school's vpn while being connected to NordVPN ?

Comment: Try installing openvpn, I believe your school instructions rely on this. It will reinstall the missing dependencies.

Comment: @Charles OpenVPN is already installed

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling - no dice

Comment: Does the NordVPN connection uses OpenVPN aswell? It could be interfering with your school's connection

Comment: The school one is Cisco-compatible and the Nord one is OpenVPN https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1047409422/How-can-I-connect-to-NordVPN-using-Linux-Terminal.htm

I never try to have both of them up at the same time. (I need to get my server running after the quarter is over as well so I can run NordVPN on my desktop-server 24/7.)

Comment: Did you tried `apt update` , `apt --fix-broken install` , `apt install --reinstall openvpn` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working again! I noticed PyChess was one of the applications that was removed when I screwed around with OpenPLC, so I used the Ubuntu Software GUI to re-install PyChess, and, ala-kazaam! VPN was working again with the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Since your school uses Ciso based vpn, I would try to purge the package, network-manager-vpnc, and reinstall it. Maybe that would fix the problem.

`sudo apt-get purge network-manager-vpnc`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt install network-manager-vpnc`

Comment: OK, sorry for the delay.

I upgraded to 18.04, followed all the website tutorials I could, including yours, but I couldn't get MSOE's VPN to connect. Nord's, again, connects just fine, but MSOE's just shuts off immediately and kind-of just doesn't try.

I'll reinstate the bounty

Comment: I don't know how to reinstate the bounty